# Ruby installed in multiple locations. Is this normal on macOS?

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew

I have macOS version 10.13.2 along with brew and brew cask installed. 
Recently I started programming in ruby and wanted to install a few new versions of ruby.  It was suggested to me to use rvm to handle multiple versions of ruby.

If I run `rvm list` I get the following (which seems correct as far as the ruby versions go):

```
rvm rubies
ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]    
ruby-2.3.5 [ x86_64 ]    
ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.5.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

However, when I run `which -a ruby` I get the following:

```
/Users/vimusr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Is it normal for ruby to show up in 2 different locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's not really related to Ruby. It's more about shell and RVM.
You use `-a` options for `which`. 
From man:

> -a      List all instances of executables found (instead of just the first one of each).

So it's normal situation in your case. You have system Ruby installed via Brew. It's located at `/usr/bin/ruby`.

Also you have Ruby installed via RVM. RVM modifies `$PATH` environment variable to you be able to run RVM's Ruby.

**Updated:**

I've mixed up. Ruby located at `/usr/bin/ruby` is shipped with Mac OS by itself rather than install via Brew.

Comment: mac os has got ruby installed by default, it's shipped with new mac os.

Comment: "You have system Ruby installed via Brew. It's located at `/usr/bin/ruby`" -> That’s false. `/usr/bin/ruby` is the system Ruby; Homebrew can’t install anything at this location.